# Field is still posted even when not displayed

Tags: reactjs

A field is displayed based on the truthyness of a variable :

```
const [paymentCash, setPaymentCash] = useState(null);
...
const onSubmit = async (values) => {
        try {
            const response = await createGroupService(values);
            onSuccess(_getText('notif.msg.group.created.ok'));
        } catch (error) {
            hideLoader();
        }
    };
<Formik
            initialValues={isUpdate ? updateFormValues : initialValues}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
        >
            {(formik) => {
                    ...
                    <FormikControl
                        formik={formik}
                        control="single-select"
                        label={_getText("billing.model")}
                        name="billingModel"
                        options={billingModels}
                        onChangeEffect={(inputValue) => {
                                                            setPaymentCash(inputValue.code == "CASH" ? true : false);
                                                        }
                                        }
                    />
...
{paymentCash && <FormikControl
                            control="input"
                            label={_getText("prix.achat")}
                            name="purchasePrice"
                            placeholder={_getText("prix.achat")}
                            type="number"
                        />}
...
<Button text="Submit" type="submit" />
```

When paymentCash is false and when submitting the form then I still get the field purchasePrice posted. So how to fix that ?

Comment: How is it rendering when `paymentCash` is false?

Comment: Can you add full code to debug?

Comment: @Nick when `paymentCash` is false then the field `purchasePrice` is not displayed

Comment: The obvious 2 things to check here is whether `paymentCash` is actually false and whether a `<FormikControl ... name="purchasePrice"...` isn't rendered elsewhere. The snippet you provided makes it all but impossible to check either. It would be great to have a reproducible example of this problem.

Comment: @Yadab look at the edit of the post

Comment: How are you setting the `paymentCash`?

Comment: Neet more about setting paymentCash, where, when !?

Comment: @Yadab I edited the post to include the setting of the variable

Comment: Not sure what is the use case but try changing to `inputValue.code === "CASH"` Also can you check the value of inputValue if it contains code key?

Comment: @Yadab I have changed the test to `===` , and `inputValue` contains the key `code` : `{ pk: 1, code: "CASH" }`